# jQuery check if value is in object

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have a page with user accounts and check boxes. On save, I need to add all the values of the check boxes to an object as long as they don't already exist in there.

I had this working when I was using an associative array as I was only storing a single value at the time. I am now storing it as an object and I need to make sure the QID (this is unique) doesn't already exist in the object.

Is there an elegant way to approach this?

```
var selectedUsers = [];

$(tab).find(".cb:checked").each(function() {
        // If the QID is not already in the array, add it
        if(jQuery.inArray($(this).val(), selectedUsers) === -1) {
            selectedUsers.push({
                "qid": $(this).val(),
                "first": $(this).data('emp_first'),
                "last": $(this).data('emp_last'),
                "department": $(this).data('emp_dept')
            });
        }
    });
```

Comment: maybe you don't need the if condition

Comment: JS doesn't really have associative arrays...if you have string keys, then you need a regular object, not an array. I suggest creating an object rather than an array for selectedUsers, then you can index it by qid.

Comment: An array of objects is still better here in my opinion. It is, after all, a list of users.

Comment: ...but it depends on other stuff actually, so not *always* better, depends on how it's being used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just keep a map that you add the ID's to, that way it's easy and efficient to check if an ID exist, regardless of the data structure in the array

```
var selectedUsers = [];
var addedUsers    = {};

$(tab).find(".cb:checked").each(function() {

    var qid = this.value;

    if ( !(qid in addedUsers) ) {
       selectedUsers.push({
          qid   : qid,
          first : $(this).data('emp_first'),
          last  : $(this).data('emp_last'),
          department : $(this).data('emp_dept')
       });
       addedUsers[qid] = 'x';
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a generic lookup function then use it:

```
  function lookup(myArray, searchTerm, property, firstOnly) {
    var found = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
      if (myArray[i][property] === searchTerm) {
        found.push(myArray[i]);
        if (firstOnly) break; //if only the first 
      }
    }
    return found;
  }
```

Use it:

```
var existUser = lookup(selectedUsers,"qid",$(this).val(),true);
if(existUser && existUser.length){// it returned a match if len > 0
   push it here
}
```

---

That is a bit risky if someone has a lookup already, so let's namespace it with some others: )(change `myApp` to yours)

used:

```
var existUser = myApp.arrayObj.lookup(selectedUsers,"qid",$(this).val(),true);
```

OR use the contains:

```
var hasUser = myApp.arrayObj.contains(selectedUsers,"qid",$(this).val());
```

Functions:

```
var myApp = myApp || {};
myApp.arrayObj = {
  indexOf: function(myArray, searchTerm, property) {
    for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
      if (myArray[i][property] === searchTerm) return i;
    }
    return -1;
  },
  indexAllOf: function(myArray, searchTerm, property) {
    var ai = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
      if (myArray[i][property] === searchTerm) ai.push(i);
    }
    return ai;
  },
  lookup: function(myArray, searchTerm, property, firstOnly) {
    var found = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
      if (myArray[i][property] === searchTerm) {
        found.push(myArray[i]);
        if (firstOnly) break; //if only the first 
      }
    }
    return found;
  },
  lookupAll: function(myArray, searchTerm, property) {
    return this.lookup(myArray, searchTerm, property, false);
  },
  remove: function(myArray, searchTerm, property, firstOnly) {
    for (var i = myArray.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      if (myArray[i][property] === searchTerm) {
        myArray.splice(i, 1);
        if (firstOnly) break; //if only the first term has to be removed
      }
    }
  },
  contains: function(myArray, searchTerm, property){
      return this.indexOf(myArray, searchTerm, property) !== -1;
  }
};
```

Comment: This is a very thoughtful response, but a lot of this stuff is implemented in native JS. I think you could accomplish pretty much each one without a single `for` loop.

Comment: Pretty backward compatible to older browsers and I tested these for speed, even against some native stuff in Chrome and found this as fast or faster in many instances. i.e. map and .keys etc.  Even the native will need to iterate in a loop somehow.

Comment: For example on 10,000 objects with 1200 matches  lookupAll Took: 0.7949999999999591msecs found:1200

Comment: Fair enough but is it faster than lodash? I feel like you either go with something that's been highly optimized (like lodash) or you go with native stuff for improved readability / higher level concepts.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a variety of things here, but maybe `some` is what you want.

```
if (!selectedUsers.some(function (user) {
  return user.qid === $(this).val()
})) {
   selectedUsers.push(...)
}
```

This says, if none of the items in the array have a qid that matches, push the new one.

More elegantly written:

```
var qid = $(this).val()
if (!selectedUsers.some(user => user.qid === qid) {
  selectedUsers.push(..)
}
```